# An inequality for a recursive relation

Tags: calculus, inequality

Define
$$
f\left( n+1\right) =f\left( n\right)\cdot e^{f\left( n\right) }
$$
for all $n\in \left\{ 1,2,...\right\} $, with $f\left( 1\right) =-1$.

Show that for all $n$
$$
f\left( n\right) \geq -\frac{1}{n}
$$

---

Note that $f(n)<0$ for all $n$. Induction seems to fail (or, very hard) since one term is negative and the other is positive in the multiplication.

Comment: Please do not delete questions with good answers. Others have devoted effort to answer your question; deleting the question is disrespectful of their effort and prevents others from benefiting from your question and its answers.

Answer (score 2):

Let $g(x)=xe^x$. Since $g'(x)=(1+x)e^x$, $g$ is strictly increasing on $[-1,+\infty)$. Also note that 
$$e^{\frac{1}{n}}>1+\frac{1}{n}\Longrightarrow g(-\frac{1}{n})>-\frac{1}{n+1}.$$

Therefore, if $f(n)\ge-\frac{1}{n}$, then 
$$f(n+1)=g(f(n))\ge g(-\frac{1}{n})>-\frac{1}{n+1}.$$